# How to visualize the label image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, simpleitk

I want to segment an image. I used simple thresholding method.For that I read the image and convert it into array and then img is converted

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np
header = sitk.ReadImage("Sub1.png")
img = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(header)
a=img
img = ((img > 20) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
# To visualize the labels image in RGB with needs a image with 0-255 range
img_T1_255 = sitk.Cast(sitk.RescaleIntensity(a), sitk.sitkUInt8)
myshow(sitk.LabelOverlay(img_T1_255, img), "Basic Thresholding")
```

Error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-c44b80227919> in <module>()
      8 img = ((img > 20) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
      9 # To visualize the labels image in RGB with needs a image with 0-255 range
---> 10 img_T1_255 = sitk.Cast(sitk.RescaleIntensity(a), sitk.sitkUInt8)

~/sitkpy/lib/python3.5/site-packages/SimpleITK/SimpleITK.py in RescaleIntensity(image1, outputMinimum, outputMaximum)
  58734 
  58735     """
> 58736     return _SimpleITK.RescaleIntensity(image1, outputMinimum, outputMaximum)
  58737 class RichardsonLucyDeconvolutionImageFilter(ImageFilter_2):
  58738     """

TypeError: in method 'RescaleIntensity', argument 1 of type 'itk::simple::Image const &'
```

Comment: sorry if I misled you and told you to work on raw pixel data, always used `SimpleITK` just for loading MetaImage files and processed them with other libs (like numpy here), while it has a lot of processing functions of its own like the overloaded operators in your other question.

Comment: can you help me to extract slices from 305*305*39 nii image

Comment: img = sitk.ReadImage("S1.nii") then ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have converted the SimpleITK sitk.Image object, 'header' ( this variable name indicates a miss understanding of what sitk.ReadImage returns ), to a numpy nd.array. The SimpleITK filters, functions and overloaded operators only work on sitk.ImageTypes.

Comment: No. You need to examine your image. Determine what the multiple channels mean, and determine what you intend to do by "thresholding" the multi-channel image. You may want to select a single channel with sitk.VectorIndexSelectionCast, or perform something like sitk.VectorMagnitude to combine the channels.